# Matrices with Linked List Implementation

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to read matrices from the text file like:

```
2 3
52 7 100
90 36 90
22 35 62
56 51 23
58 98 74
86 32 45
```

First line indicates row and column size. Then I should read the data in the matrices and create a linked list with them. I also should find the sum matrix (it's not a problem). I wrote something, but I think it's not linked list implementation; it's just 2 dimensional array of structures. Do I do/think wrong? Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: your hunch is right! just google for it, K&R should have an example.

Comment: thanks. I already search but I couldn't find useful for me. Should I write it all over again ?

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: thanks but it's not relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following will help you get started

First, check out code at [singly_linked_list](http://en.literateprograms.org/Singly_linked_list_%28C%29). It has everything you need, nicely laid out and explained - struct NODE, create, prepend, and foreach/traversal. That page has a lot more to offer, actually.

Some pseudo code:

1. get row, col // you already got it
2. write a helper function `NODE* process_line(line, col)` which parses a line that has been read from file, tokenizes it, does atoi, and returns a linked-list that contains the row. It could return null to indicate errors, for example not enough values, non-integers, etc. Must free memory if you are returning null.
3. you need 1 main linked list that stores your rows. Each node in this linked list will itself be a linked list that represents the row. (Another possible solution can be that each row is represented simply by an array of ints, of a known length).
4. read file, line by line. Process the line to get the row in a suitable representation (a linked list, I have assumed). Push this into your main linked-list of rows as yet another node
5. To compute sum, you need to traverse the outer linked-list. To process each row/node in this, you will need to traverse that row linked-list.

Iterating linked lists is easy

```
// modeling after
int list_foreach(NODE *node, int(*func)(void*))
{
   while(node) {
     if(func(node->data)!=0) return -1;
     node=node->next;
   }
   return 0;
}
// a more general purpose traversal which tracks state (a reduce-like op)
int list_traverse(NODE *node, void* state, int(*func)(void* state, void*data))
{
  while(node) {
    if (func(state, node->data)!=0) return -1; // something broke
    node=node->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

// Your actual summing functions

```
int sum_a_row(void* prev_state, void* data){
   int* psum = (int*)prev_state;
   *psum += (int)data;
   return 0; // a successful summing
}

int sum_matrix(void* prev_state, void* data) {
    NODE* row = (NODE*)data;
    int* psum = (int*)prev_state;
    int row_sum = 0;
    int error = list_traverse(row, &row_sum, sum_a_row);
    *psum += row_sum;
    return 0; // success in summing
}

int matrix_sum = 0;
int error = list_traverse(matrix_head_node, &matrix_sum, sum_matrix);
```

HTH. Forgive my coding style and any errors. You can simplify further if you assume a valid matrix when you reach summing.